# create log4j depending on level using .properties file

Tags: log4j, properties-file

I have to create new file for each level like:

1. fatel.log for only FATAL
2. error.log for only ERROR
3. warn.log  for only WARN etc. 
   how can i achieve this thing in changing this properties file.

Here is my log4j.properties file:

**FILE**

```
# level : OFF,FATAL,ERROR,WARN,INFO,DEBUG,ALL
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,CONSOLE,A1
log4j.addivity.org.apache=true

# for console
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[INFO] %d - %c -%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File=C:/hibernateSqlite.log
log4j.appender.A1.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L : %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I've never done it, I guess it will be something like:

```
log4j.appender.AppDebug.filter.DebugFilter=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
log4j.appender.AppDebug.filter.DebugFilter.acceptOnMatch=true
log4j.appender.AppDebug.filter.DebugFilter.levelToMatch=DEBUG
```

The type of the `AppDebug` appender could be `DailyRollingFileAppender`, as in your case, with the remaining configuration options along.